# Display first tab on page load (jquery) except on mobile screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a little JS script to toggle 3 different tabs (section1, 2 and 3) on a page. Right now, all tabs are hidden by default. I would like to show the 1st tab (section1) to be displayed on load by default, except when the mobile-navbar is visible (so that no tabs are displayed when the page is displayed on a mobile device). 
I'm at a total lost. Would appreciate some guidance! Many thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs-section .title a").on("click", function() { 
        if($(this).parents(".tab-content").hasClass("active-section"))
        {
            $(".tab-content").removeClass("active-section");
        }
        else
        {
            $(".tab-content").removeClass("active-section");
            $(this).parents(".tab-content").addClass("active-section");
        }
        if($("#mobile-navbar").is(":visible"))
        {
            $('html, body, #container, #inner-container').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
            }, 1000);
        }
        return false;
    });
    $( '#mobile-navigation' ).dlmenu();
});
```

--

```
<div id="tabs-section">
  <div id="section1" class="tab-content">
    <h4 class="title"><a href="#">Section1</a></h4>
       <div class="section-content">
       </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="tab-content">
    <h4 class="title"><a href="#">Section2</a></h4>
       <div class="section-content">
       </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="tab-content">
    <h4 class="title"><a href="#">Section3</a></h4>
        <div class="section-content">
        </div>
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hbezjLpn/

Comment: You don't have `a` inside your `.title`. Can you post your code inside a fiddle?

Comment: oh yes I did remove it without paying attention.

Comment: Just added a fiddle with the code : http://jsfiddle.net/hbezjLpn/